# express routing match a url

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

what regex should one use in express to match a url. If my endpoint looks like this

www.mydomain.com/v1/https://www.url-to-be-matched.com.

I want to accept https://www.url-to-be-matched.com. as params.
I have tried this

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/v1/:url',function(req,res){
console.log(req.params.url);
});
```

The above is not matching the url.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have to encode the passed url with the `encodeURI()` method.

Comment: what changes I need to make in my code I don't understand after going to encodeURI doc.

Comment: You have a URL embedded within another URL's path. For this you should escape the embedded URL for easy extraction. That is, the request from your client should be to `www.mydomain.com/v1/https%3A%2F%2Fwww.url-to-be-matched.com`. If your application generates this link, make sure the generation code performs this encoding.